# file not found exception in .net core API

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I am using .net core api when I try to retrieve image from server data is retrieve but in my front end the file not found exception is throw. Image is successfully inserted into server. How i can fix it?

This is for the desktop and mobile app to display the image. And i just try to pass the server path of the image to the front end.

> File not found exception

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Can you provide some code? How does the App load the image and what is the exact exception and back-end code used?

Comment: // result successful return path (from server) of the image  and content type 
var result = await _service.ReadPhysicalFile (productSN);
var Image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(result.FileName);
return File(Image,result.ContentType);

//exception
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\BarcodeScanner\2019-Jul\24_Confirmation_Photo.png'.
System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)

Comment: Can you please add this to your original post? You can format it there so it is easier to read.